# Facebook custom payload stripped from webhook fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

Hoping someone can provide some guidance here.  I have a fulfillment webhook in place which is preparing responses to send back to Facebook Messenger.

Text and images work fine, but I'm having trouble with audio files.

This is what my server outputs:

[image]

And this is what I see in the raw interaction log for Dialogflow. For some reason the custom payload is missing:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue here.  The Facebook custom payload should have been under the payload entity which I was missing. Below is the correct JSON structure:

[image]